# ECLIPSE 4 Plugin: How to access the workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp

I am writing an Eclipse 4 Plugin and i found, that in Eclipse 3 you could access the workbench quiet easy with:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
```

In my plugin I would like to do the same and found that i have to Inject some service, but i am not able to find out how to do this properly. 
Can someone give me a hint where to look or how this is done in Eclipse 4?

Comment: Do you mean an e4 application rather than a 3.x compatability mode app? The traditional workbench does not exist in an e4 application, nor do any of the other resource APIs (IFile, IFolder, ....)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the workbench concept does not exist in an e4 application. Seems I have to find than another way.

Comment: Note - your other question about imports is using 3.x compatabilty mode code  not e4. PlatformUI.getWorkbench works fine in 3.x compatabilty mode.

Comment: Also note that there is still a workspace location in e4 - you just have to use ordinary Java file APIs to put anything in it.